# Chern class of Hopf fibration: $S^1 \hookrightarrow S^3 \xrightarrow{\ p \, } S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

As definition, the first Chern class is an element in $H^2_{dR}(S^2)$, how can we represent it as an integer? If we change the orientation of $S^2$, then does the integer change sign?

Comment: $H^2_{dR}(S^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and has one of two possible distinguished elements in it given by one of the two possible orientations. The first Chern class is always an integer multiple of this (because both classes lift to integral cohomology). If you change the orientation, the resulting integer multiple changes sign, but the first Chern class itself doesn't.

Comment: Thanks very much! May I ask how to lift the deRham cohomology class to integer cohomology?